# refer to variable in xpath command in bash script

Tags: bash, xpath

I've got this in a for loop in a bash script:

```
xpath $f '//bad/objdesc/desc[$i]' > $f.$i.xml
```

$i is the counter.

It doesn't work.

How do I refer to $i properly in the brackets of the desc element?

Thanks.

Comment: Where are you getting this `xpath` command from? I'm more accustomed to using XMLStarlet to execute XPath queries -- which has a proper mechanism for passing in variables. The tool you're using now may do so also.

Comment: ...seriously, though -- the XPath standard specifies a language, not a command-line tool. If you have a command-line tool called `xpath`, you need to specify which one and from where for folks to be able to provide specific, on-point help regarding it.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: This xpath is  installed with libxml, so it is usually the same

Comment: @BeniBela, I have Ubuntu, Mint and Arch Linux systems immediately available. The Arch system has its `xpath` as a perl script; the others have no executable by that name at all. All of them have libxml. Perhaps you're thinking of `xmllint --xpath`?

Comment: It's a bash thing, and the answer is correct. No need to specify anything else. "seriously"

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Here is installed on a OpenSUSE and a  Debian system, where  the package is called libxml-xpath-perl.

Comment: @user2697528, it's only correct when `$i` is a number. For arbitrary strings, it absolutely is not. Consider the case when you want to pass a string containing a `]` character; if you use this same technique in that case, the `]` is treated as XPath syntax, not as data.

Comment: @user2697528 ...you might note that nobody else -- and Glenn Jackman and DigitalTrauma are both folks who know bash fairly well, although as far as I know they *don't* know XPath -- has disputed my statements on this point. Which is to say that we're all subject-matter experts who've interacted before and respect each other fairly well; you don't need to feel like I'm attacking someone who's trying to help you -- I'm just trying to point out that the approaches they're currently offering have limits, and shouldn't be used outside of them, and gently prodding for answers without said limits.

Comment: ...and no, `xpath` is not "a bash thing". Come ask in irc.freenode.org #bash and we'll tell you the same -- it doesn't ship with bash and is not part of the POSIX-standardized toolchain guaranteed to be available for bash. @BeniBela correctly described the tool you most likely have available -- which is a _perl_ thing, and a rather limited one at that.

Comment: The problem had to do with bash. Drop it. All this chatter is superfluous. I repeat, DigitalTrauma answered my question correctly. Thanks again, DigitalTrauma.

Comment: @user2697528, I do not ask you to reject the answer DigitalTrauma provided -- it's a perfectly fine answer, within the given bounds (integer values only). All I ask is that you read and understand my objections, and thus the limitations on when the techniques that answer teaches are appropriate. Beyond that? My comments and additional answer aren't just for you, but for everyone with a similar question wanting to learn more about how best to solve it. (And because it's not just for you, it's not your place to say when discussion is to stop; you're welcome to drop out at any time).

Comment: "seriously though," you say. work on your tone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use double quotes instead, so that the variable gets expanded instead of being treated literally as `$i`:

```
xpath "$f" "//bad/objdesc/desc[$i]" > "$f.$i.xml"
```

From the [`bash` manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Single-Quotes):

> 3.1.2.2 Single Quotes
>
> Enclosing characters in single quotes (‘'’) preserves the literal value of each character within the quotes. A single quote may not occur between single quotes, even when preceded by a backslash.
>
> 3.1.2.3 Double Quotes
>
> Enclosing characters in double quotes (‘"’) preserves the literal value of all characters within the quotes, with the exception of ‘$’, ‘`’, ‘\’, and, when history expansion is enabled, ‘!’. The characters ‘$’ and ‘`’ retain their special meaning within double quotes (see Shell Expansions). The backslash retains its special meaning only when followed by one of the following characters: ‘$’, ‘`’, ‘"’, ‘\’, or newline. Within double quotes, backslashes that are followed by one of these characters are removed. Backslashes preceding characters without a special meaning are left unmodified. A double quote may be quoted within double quotes by preceding it with a backslash. If enabled, history expansion will be performed unless an ‘!’ appearing in double quotes is escaped using a backslash. The backslash preceding the ‘!’ is not removed.

Comment: FYI, I'd expect there to be a mechanism to pass in variables specific to the XPath interpreter, similar to awk's `-vname=value`. Otherwise, you end up prone to injection attacks -- so just explaining the bash side of things isn't necessarily a complete answer. XMLStarlet certainly supports this; I can't speak to the `xpath` tool they're using here, though.

Comment: ...also, suggesting leaving the filename unquoted (on either side of the redirection) isn't great form.

Comment: ...well, maybe I should have changed "expect" to "hope". It looks like on at least some systems, `xpath` is provided by a dinky little perl script, with none of the serious functionality (including bind parameters) one would hope for from an XML processing toolkit.

Comment: I wouldn't expect it at all. In my experience, awk is rather unique in this capability.

Comment: @glennjackman xmlstarlet supports it, jq (an equivalent tool for JSON) supports it, the basex command-line interface supports it... and places where there isn't an explicit `-v`, there's typically at least a way to access environment variables (as in perl), providing another way to pass in data without the risk of interpretation as code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a much more efficient alternate approach, for the specific indexing-into-a-list case.

```
counter=1
while IFS='' read -r -d $'\x03' line; do
  printf '%s' "$line" >"%f.$(( counter++ )).xml"
done < <(xmlstarlet sel -t -m //bad/objdesc/desc -v . -o $'\x03')
```

This runs `xmlstarlet` (a more capable alternative to `xpath`) *only once*, and retrieves the entire set of values (even should they be multiline) into a bash array, where they can be accessed as `${array[0]}`, `${array[1]}`, etc.

It has the caveat that values containing the literal EOT character within their contents will be split into multiple values on that character.

---

A word on safety:

Expanding query parameters -- whether XPath, SQL, or otherwise -- within double quotes in bash opens you up to [query injection attacks](http://xkcd.com/327/). Let's say you had a variable with a customer IDs, and you were looking up account balances; if you used `xpath "//record[customer='$id' and record='$rec']"`, a customer who could provide literal values for `$rec` could also look up content belonging to customers with a different ID by escaping  the quotes.

**The safe alternative is to use a tool that lets you pass your query in single-quotes**, and pass your parameters out-of-band, as with a `--var name="$value"` parameter. Until it has this capability, I cannot advise the Perl `xpath` tool for general use.

Should someone other than the original poster of the question be considering using the `xpath` tool with user-provided or untrusted data, please keep the above in mind.

Comment: But he wanted to save it as files, not split it in an array. Anyways, to put it in a array there is a simpler solution with my [Xidel](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html): eval "$(xidel $f -e //bad/objdesc/desc --output-format bash)"

Comment: @BeniBela, that's great! You might consider adding an answer on-point, and adding more quotes (even `eval` needs its arguments to be quoted if you don't want them string-split and glob-expanded before processing).

Comment: @BeniBela ...also, I've edited this to save each entry to a file; the general break-on-EOT approach is applicable to much more than just arrays.

Comment: @BeniBela ...by the way, looking at the documentation, I don't see Xidel offering a mechanism for bind parameters. Consider this a feature request. :)

Comment: The quotes for eval might not matter, because it outputs everything between '' or $'' quotes

Comment: I did not think that direction would be expected. But  it should work with  -e $'$var := system("sh -c \'echo ""$var""\'")' to bind variable var (if I did not screw the nested " and ' escaping up now).

Comment: @BeniBela, they actually still do -- look at the difference between `func() { printf '%s\n' "echo hello" "echo world"; }; eval $(func)` and the same but with `eval "$(func)"`.

Comment: but it will only output assignments like a=1 b[0]=2 b[1]=$'3\n\n' ... they stay the same if written on a single line

Comment: @BeniBela, yes, if you restrict the domain enough, you can make unquoted use safe -- but why would you do that, when the quoted form avoids restrictions? (Wildcard expansion is another issue; if you have unquoted `[foo]` strings, the shell can see them as glob expansions and either expand them to files, if such files exist, or simply delete those arguments altogether if the `nullglob` shell option is turned on. Granted, people don't often leave `nullglob` on, but depending on it being off makes the practices you're asking people to follow more fragile).

Comment: Since it is a tool, it is better if it works without and with; otherwise people might forget them (I always do) and get security issues

Comment: @BeniBela, indeed -- your current usage may have bugs, but only ones easy to hit when `nullglob` is enabled, and it's a rather obscure option. At the same time, it's better for documentation to demonstrate best practices.